# Get xpath from jaxb object

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb

Is there a built in library that will allow be to get xpath expression or value from a jaxb property.

For example, if I the following class is generated by jaxb (annotations removed)

```
@ ... 
public Person {
  private Address address;
  private String name;
}
```

I want to find out what xpath expression the address property maps to.

Is there an existing library to do that (without using reflection)?